# jQuery scroll after click on accordion

Tags: jquery

I'm using an accordion on mobile view and am looking for a way to scroll the visitor to the accordions title tab when clicked.

My code is kind of working, but since the position of 'acctab' changes on click, the scroll only takes you to it's original position (if that makes sense).

```
$(".acctab").click(function () {

        var target = this,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 300, 'swing', function () {
        });

     });
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `$(document).on("click",".acctab",function(){...});` instead of `$(".acctab").click(function () {...});`

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

You want to use the accordion `activate` callback in your accordion constructor instead of observing the click event on the element.

```
$("#tabs").accordion({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        // Check the active tab
        if (ui.newPanel == 3) { // Or whichever tab you want to apply your action to
            // Your stuff
        }
    }
});
```

This will trigger your callback when the accordion is done opening a given tab's panel.